# Why is my Android Studio Generated Signed APK not working on some brands of Android Device?

Tags: android, apk, device, compatibility, android-hardware

Been having trouble with this one for weeks and searched throughout forums for solutions.

I have an Android App that can be installed on some brands of devices but won't install on others. On some devices It keeps getting a package error every time i install it.
And in some devices it even hangs just by looking at the APK file.

But if i plug the device that has a package error on the PC and install the apk through android studio, it will install the app.

Is this some kind of hardware problem? Or some kind of hardware compatibility issue?

The brand that i'm sure it will install is Samsung. Brands that it won't install is LG or ASUS.

I already checked the versions and almost all the devices has the same SDK api.

Min-SDK: 15
Target-SDK: 25

I even updated Android Studio and gradle to latest versions.

Comment: Can you tell what error gets displayed when it doesn't get installed?

Comment: try to install the apk from third party file explorer.I'm getting this issue since i have updated android studio.It is saying can't open file

Comment: It says. "Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped." I can't see what specific error it is in the terminal of android studio. Because it installs the app when i install it using android studio.

Comment: play service is updated

Comment: connect your device w/ usb, open `cmd` and run `adb devices` (you should see your device). you can run `adb logcat` to watch the log (no Android Studio required). now attempt to install your apk (in whatever way triggers the problem) and get the error from the logcat.. you can pipe that to a file to make viewing easier.. `adb logcat > logfile.txt` (followed by ctrl+c). ..based on the accepted answer I bet you will find a permissions related exception in there.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i'm looking for to log the errors. Because it won't show up when i install it in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. I had the same issue. I forgot to add same permissions in manifest. I added these permissions in manifest as well as mike said. Then clean and build and worked like a charm.
2. Conclusion: If you are giving the permissions programmatically in class then make sure the same permissions you must declare in AndroidManifest.xml file.
3. make sure you have an icon and that the image is no bigger than 60 by 60 pixels
4. App icon should be png formtat
5. remove unused images and large size image in the Media Section Now it will be works.

Comment: What are those permissions?  I just basically add the permissions in the manifest.

Comment: i think you are using dangerous permission , can you see your all permission ?

Comment: The permission i just use are only for internet purposes. Wifi and Network

Comment: its ok , then check you app icon and image size , please follow all five points

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will try them later.

Comment: welcome you, please upvote the answer then some will be help

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by allowing cleartexttraffic or you can also convert http to https .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application
     `enter code here`  ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     ...>
     ...
 </application>  
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.